# Is there any available free & open source implementation of RSA-2048 for SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to do some cryptography for SQL Server 2000, and I know that only SQL 2005+ comes with built-in functionality for doing this natively.

Do you know any open source implementation that I can use for free of RSA-2048 cryptography?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [Extended Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214418%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to do this. You can make them yourself building on one of the many C or C++ open-source implementations or the Windows CryptoAPI.

Alternatively a quick Google search reveals [XP_CRYPT](http://xpcrypt.com/products.html) which is an implementation of this (but it is not free if you want RSA with any secure keylength).

Answer (score 0):

Check open source libraries under [Elliptic curve cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography#Open_source)
Which should you should be able to use following [developer guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522480%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I can't use these libraries from SQL Server 2000 procedures =/

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't check the version numbers